# How to sort in an API call for College ScoreCard

Tags: api, collegescorecard

I'm trying to sort an API query by size of students, but I can't figure out how to get the API to accept the &sort parameter. Can someone provide me an example? I'm referring to the documentation [here](https://github.com/RTICWDT/open-data-maker/blob/master/API.md) but it isn't very clear (to me, a noob at API's). I've already tried the following:

```
let collegeDataAPIoptions = {
    url: 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json' +
        '?school.' +
        'operating=0,1' +
        '&_fields=' +
        'id,' +
        'school.name,' +
        '2019.student.size,' +
        '2019.academics.program_percentage.education' +
        '&sort=2019.student.size' +
        '&api_key=[redacted]'
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
StatusCodeError: 400 - "{\"error\":{\"error\":\"unknown_column\",\"message\":\"Only select columns are available for filtering. 
Please see the data documentation column \\\"INDEX\\\" to find out which ones are allowed.\",\"input\":\"Unknown column '2019_student_size' in 'order clause'\"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after more debugging it looks like it works if the field (in &sort=[field]) doesn't start with a number. If I start it with 'latest' then it works just fine, even though in this case 'latest' and 2019 should be interchangeable.